# Laravel - put or with?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I have two fragments of code, and as far as i know both of them are doing pretty much the same thing.

Which approach is correct in Laravel 5.5?

1.

```
$request->session()->put('login-error', '');
return redirect()->route('welcome');
```

2.

```
return redirect()->route('welcome')->with('login-error', '');
```

Comment: go fo the 2nd one bro.. use clean code.. don't double your work on same result..follow the best practice bro.. its Laravel not CI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first approach is the appropriate one.

Comment: Out of interest. The Laravel documentation does not prefer one over the other method (at least I dont see it). How you come to that conclusion?

Comment: True, but obviously there has to be a session before it is concluded with a redirect. Its cool for debugging purposes.Think about that.

Comment: @olasunkanmi how is it better for debugging?

Comment: For those coming from procedural PHP, they have to know each steps taken to arrive at a particular solution. Though the other option is cool for cleaner code, I feel, the first option is self explanatory to some extent. @alexey Mezenin

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement,
In second method the session is only available on the next page
but in the first method, there is no such restriction

Comment: more info [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data)

Answer (score 0):

I can't say one way is better than the other in all cases. But when redirecting, I prefer to use `with()` because of better readability.

BTW, you can use [concise syntax](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#use-shorter-and-more-readable-syntax-where-possible):

```
session(['var' => $value]);
```

Instead of:

```
$request->session()->put('var', $value);
```

Comment: Nice collection of tips on your GH :-)

Comment: @Konafets Thanks. ) Hope this collection will help Laravel developers to write better code.

Comment: I wrote an article about better location for Validation rules: https://medium.com/@konafets/a-better-place-for-your-validation-rules-in-laravel-f5e3f5b7cc